# How to read in this?

Tags: scheme, racket

I have the following test example to be able to use `read`, but encounters some problem:

```
#lang racket
(struct test (num) #:prefab)
(define s3 (read (open-input-string "((AK= #s(test .)) (AV))")))
(match s3
   [`((AK= ,(struct test (val))) (AV)) (displayln val)])
```

It will give out `read: unexpected`)'`

I know it is because of the `.`, but my source will contain a lot of this kind of thing, then the question is that how can I read them in racket?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable reading dots with [`read-accept-dot`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Reading.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._read-accept-dot%29%29) and [`read-accept-infix-dot`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Reading.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._read-accept-infix-dot%29%29), but that just makes it an error if there's a dot.  So it sounds like you'd want to use a [custom readtable](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/readtables.html) here (read the [guide section](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/hash-reader.html#%28part._readtable%29) too):

```
#lang racket
(struct test (num) #:prefab)
(define rt:no-dots
  (make-readtable (current-readtable)
                  #\. 'non-terminating-macro (  _ #'|.|)))
(define (read-with-dots str)
  (parameterize ([current-readtable rt:no-dots])
    (read (open-input-string str))))
(define s3 (read-with-dots "((AK= #s(test .)) (AV))"))
(match s3
   [`((AK= ,(struct test (val))) (AV)) (displayln val)])
```

Alternatively, you can make the dots get treated as comments:

```
(define rt:no-dots
  (make-readtable (current-readtable)
                  #\. 'non-terminating-macro
                  (  _ (make-special-comment #f))))
```

Comment: Thanks! and now I guess I will need to extend the readtable with all the things that couldn't be read in before like this...

Comment: @monica: Bear in mind that if you have some data that is far enough from Racket's syntax, then you can just as well go with some simpler regexp-based thing, or, on the other end, you can build a whole parser.

Comment: I encountered the problem of how to correctly read in the `(` or `)` in racket...then thanks to your suggestion, I just abandon the readtable extension approach. Instead, i get ahold of all the instances  from different runs of the programs and do What I wanted before, rather than using the serialization/dis-serialization approach.

Comment: @monica: if you're running into more problems around this, then instead of more comments (which are intentionally ineffective for this sort of thing) you can also just send an email to our [mailing list](http://racket-lang.org/community.html).